# Print all lines but concatenate consecutive lines matching a pattern

Tags: awk, concatenation, match

I have a file that contains the following data:

```
;Citation1 begins here and contains characters including , . and numbers

DATA 1 259.85 101000 0.094837707 0.9089 / 
         2 266.07 101000 0.097842938 0.8997 / 
         3 270.95 101000 0.105071894 0.8899 / 
         4 273.35 101000 0.112016587 0.8849 / 
         5 278.75 101000 0.134569045 0.87 / 

;Citation2 begins here and contains characters including , . and numbers but
;this one continues on the next line

DATA 1 259.85 101000 0.094837707 0.9089 / 
         2 266.07 101000 0.097842938 0.8997 / 
         3 270.95 101000 0.105071894 0.8899 / 
         4 273.35 101000 0.112016587 0.8849 / 
         5 278.75 101000 0.134569045 0.87 /
```

I would like to have all the lines printed into a new file. However, when consecutive lines begin with the same character (here ";"), I would like to concatenate them to the same line. The above input file would therefore appear as:

```
;Citation1 begins here and contains characters including , . and numbers

DATA 1 259.85 101000 0.094837707 0.9089 / 
         2 266.07 101000 0.097842938 0.8997 / 
         3 270.95 101000 0.105071894 0.8899 / 
         4 273.35 101000 0.112016587 0.8849 / 
         5 278.75 101000 0.134569045 0.87 / 

;Citation2 begins here and contains characters including , . and numbers but this one continues on the next line

DATA 1 259.85 101000 0.094837707 0.9089 / 
         2 266.07 101000 0.097842938 0.8997 / 
         3 270.95 101000 0.105071894 0.8899 / 
         4 273.35 101000 0.112016587 0.8849 / 
         5 278.75 101000 0.134569045 0.87 /
```

I have tried using different variations of awk commands such as:

```
awk '/;/ && last {printf "%s","\n"last;$0}{printf "%s",$0}END{print} /;/{last=$0}' input.txt > output.txt
```

but have not been successful.

Comment: Welcome to SO, on SO we do encourage users to do add their efforts which they have put in order to fix their own problem, so kindly do add the same and let us know then.

Comment: Why not concentrate on three rules? The first looks for `/^;/` (concatenate all lines, from char 2 on, increment counter `n` skip to next record) the next checks if `n > 0` (print concatenated lines prefixed with `';'` and with an additional `'\n'`, reset your string and counter, skip to next) and the final rule `1` (default print). Give it a try and let us know where you get stuck by providing [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I edited the post to address the first comment. I tried a million variations of that line but no luck. With the second comment, I understand the logic but I am still trying to figure out the correct syntax to implement it. Thanks!

Comment: @user13758913 good job. You see what I would have posted below Ed's answer (it's hard to compete with Ed on the perfect `awk` solution). Visit the links Ed provided in the comments to investigate and correct any stray line ending problems you have in your data file. Both solutions give just what you ask for using the input copied and pasted from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '
    {
        curr = $0
        printf "%s%s", ( (prev ~ /^;/) && sub(/^;/,"") ? OFS : ors ), $0
        ors = ORS
        prev = curr
    }
    END { print "" }
' file
;Citation1 begins here and contains characters including , . and numbers

DATA 1 259.85 101000 0.094837707 0.9089 /
         2 266.07 101000 0.097842938 0.8997 /
         3 270.95 101000 0.105071894 0.8899 /
         4 273.35 101000 0.112016587 0.8849 /
         5 278.75 101000 0.134569045 0.87 /

;Citation2 begins here and contains characters including , . and numbers but this one continues on the next line

DATA 1 259.85 101000 0.094837707 0.9089 /
         2 266.07 101000 0.097842938 0.8997 /
         3 270.95 101000 0.105071894 0.8899 /
         4 273.35 101000 0.112016587 0.8849 /
         5 278.75 101000 0.134569045 0.87 /
```

Comment: Okay, that gets the cool factor over `awk '/^;/ {s=substr($0,2);cite=(n>0)?cite" "s:s; n++; next}; n>0 {print ";"cite; cite=""; n=0; next}1' file`

Comment: Thank you! Both work very well. However, is there a way to concatenate the second row of text so that it shows up on the previous line. Right now, they still appear on two separate lines but the second line is missing its ';'

Comment: As you can see in my answer that doesn't happen, it does exactly what you asked for. If you're getting a different result then either you copy/pasted my script incorrectly or your real input doesn't look like the example you posted.

Comment: I believe that the second possibility you stated is what is happening. I think my input file has something at the end of the first citation line. I am not sure what it could be since it just seems like a newline. Anyway, I will try to work around it. Thanks for your help